# Converting time to 24 hour of day format in R

Tags: r, time

I have a data frame that has day of the year, year, month, 12 hr time, and some energy data. I want to make the 12 hr formatted time data into hours of the day (1-24). The time is character class.

```
format(as.POSIXct(t, format = '%I %p'), format = "%H")
```

Where

```
t <- df$time
```

df$time== time in character class with following format:

```
"12 a.m." "3 p.m."
```

but after code I get all NA and no change in column.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried and any relevant errors. If you cannot post your data then please post code for creating a representative data set.

Comment: Are all of the times hours only, as in your example, or do some have minutes?

Comment: @neilfws there are no minutes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give an example so the result is exactly what you are looking for.. taking a stab at it...

```r
Time2 <− c("11:00 AM", "10:42 AM", "12:34 AM")
format(as.POSIXct(Time2, format = '%I:%M %p'), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Hello. The column I am trying to change is a character class with the following format "12 a.m." I was able to make hour to work so get 12 for 12 a.m. but I also got 12 for 12 p.m. I am trying to use the column of time to get hour of day in 24 hr format.
 BA.Code           date        time       Demand..MWh. doy   year   
  [1,] "AZPS"  "6/19/2017" "12 a.m. " "4494"           "170" "2017" 
  [2,] "AZPS"  "6/19/2017" "1 a.m. "  "4118"            "170" "2017" 
  [3,] "AZPS"  "6/19/2017" "2 a.m. "  "3840"            "170" "2017" "

Comment: I used format        'format(as.POSIXct(t,format='%I %p'),format="%H")'      and t=df$time column     but nothing changes and it comes back as NA

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `lubridate` solution. Assuming that all the times are formatted like your examples: hours only, followed by either "a.m." or "p.m.". Date-time conversion functions recognise only "am" or "pm" so you'll need to remove the periods.

```
library(lubridate) # install first if required

times <- c("12 a.m.", "3 p.m.")

# code with nested functions
new_times <- hour(parse_date_time(gsub("\\.", "", times), "%I %p"))

# code with pipes (easier to read, perhaps)
library(magrittr)
new_times <- times %>% 
  gsub("\\.", "", .) %>% 
  parse_date_time(., "%I %p") %>% 
  hour()
```

Result:

```
new_times
[1]  0 15
```